# Check If String Exists In Array Using Array.asList(myArray) Doesnt Work

Tags: android

I am trying to see if FTP files exists on server before uploading them as I am using FTP4J library which uploads existing files (overwrites) but my check does not work even though the file exists in the array:

```
                                    for (String ftpFolder : my_ftpFolders)
                                {
                                    FTPFile[] list = ftpClient.list(ftpFolder);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        String ftpFile = list[i].getName();

                                        Log.v("LOG", "zzz_ARRAY: " +Arrays.asList(myFiles));
                                        Log.v("LOG", "zzz_ftpFile: " +ftpFile);

                                        if (Arrays.asList(myFiles).contains(ftpFile))
                                        {
                                            Log.v("LOG", "zzz_ftpFile EXIST: " +ftpFile);
                                        }else{
                                            Log.v("LOG", "zzz_ftpFile NOT EXIST: " +ftpFile);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

Array Print (Arrays.asList(myFiles)):

```
[[/storage/emulated/0/Download/mohamed-nohassi-odxB5oIG_iA-unsplash.jpg, /storage/emulated/0/Download/atheek-mohomed-e0JOwGDsUHQ-unsplash.jpg]]
```

ftpFile Print:

```
mohamed-nohassi-odxB5oIG_iA-unsplash.jpg
```

As you can see, the file exists in the array but Array.asList(myFiles) returns false

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to seach the string `mohamed-nohassi-odxB5oIG_iA-unsplash.jpg`

in a list that does not contains it. The value in the list is `/storage/emulated/0/Download/mohamed-nohassi-odxB5oIG_iA-unsplash.jpg`, that is clearly different.
To obtain the result you're trying to achieve, you have to split the file name, and get rid of the path. You can do it with some string manipulation. First, import Collectors:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Then, you can use this code to test if the list contains the file:

```
if (Arrays.asList(myFiles).stream().map(el -> {
        String[] tokenized = el.split("/");
        return tokenized.length > 0 ? tokenized[tokenized.length-1] : "";
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(ftpFile))
```

With this code, for each element in the list you're getting just the last part after the last "/", then you're checking if the ftpFile is contained in the list you'll obtain after taking only all the last parts.

Comment: I tested your theory using the exact value and it still doesn't work:
Arrays.asList(myFiles).contains("/storage/emulated/0/Download/mohamed-nohassi-odxB5oIG_iA-unsplash.jpg"

Comment: that's strange, I've tested the code myself and it did work. Only thing I'm missing is: what's the type of myFiles variable?

Comment: ArrayList<String> myFiles = new ArrayList<String>();, furthermore, I used a String Array instead to store listing from FTP using String[] listNames = ftpClient.listNames(); which works now